# Как наложить тень на картинку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть картинка. Нужно наложить на нее как-бы прозрачную, черного цвета пленку, чтобы картинка была тусклой.
Я написал так:

```css
img {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px #000;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
```

Но почему-то не работает. Что я пишу не так?

Answer (score 2):

А Вы точно уверены, что Вам нужна **тень**? Или всё-таки равномерный полупрозрачный слой поверх всей картинки? Если слой, то с помощью box-shadow Вы такого эффекта не добьётесь - придётся использовать дополнительный элемент.

К сожалению, у img нет своих псевдоэлементов, поэтому как вариант - обернуть картинку в блок и уже с помощью его :after наложить плёнку на изображение:

```css
.img-wrap {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
.img-wrap:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap">
<img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/225396/2dc17845-391c-4e56-b49e-a3559c245e97/s1200" alt="" />
</div>
```